# onload function in jquery mobile dialog not working

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Hi i'm working in jquery mobile.
In which i'm triggering a dialog of another html page using

```
$.mobile.changePage('mypopup.html',{transition:'pop',role : 'dialog', data: {'selQty':'5'}});
```

and the  dialog loaded succesfully.

My problem is i'm using onload function in body tag of  mypopup.html

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

which is not working. 
is there any problem in my code or do i need to follow alternate way.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add event like this:

```
$('#pageId').bind('pageshow', function(){

});
```

pageId is id attribute in your `<div data-role="page" id="pageId">`.

Check this page for more events: [jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: Hi Borewitsch thx for ur reply.
I tried your answer.

inserted this code
$('#pageId').bind('pageshow', function(){
alert('demo');
});

in mypopup.html but its not working

Comment: did you set an id properly in your html and script?

Comment: yes i did.
<div data-role="page" id="pageId">
...
</div>

and  above mentioned script code in head tag

Comment: There is another important thing about jqm. You have to put links to .js or .css files, as well as <script> tags inside page div. It should help

Comment: Thanks Borewitsch it works and also i moved the script from head tag to inside the page div

Comment: i added like this in head. <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#hi').bind('pageshow', function(){
                          console.log('called');
            });
            </script> .  in body i added,  <div id="hi" data-role="page" >. Still its not working. am i missing anything?

Comment: hi yokks for this, script tag should be added next to the div.
<body >
<div id="hi" data-role="page" >
<script type="text/javascript"> $('#hi').bind('pageshow', function(){ console.log('called'); }); 
</div>
</body>